# Hex value after executing instruction

Tags: assembly

I am studying for a Assembly test, and I've been having trouble determining how to determine the values after a set of instructions.

What hex value is in ax after executing all these instructions?

```
mov ax, -4
imul ah
imul al
ANSWER: AX=0010
```

> From what I put together, the value of ax, before the imul instructions, should be FFFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imul` acts differently depending on the size of the operand. `imul ah` is the **signed** multiplication `AX = AL * AH` (no `DX`). Let's do it step by step:

```
mov ax, -4
```

AX is now FFFCh which implies that AH = FFh (= -1 in an 8-bit context) and AL = FCh (= -4 in an 8-bit context).

```
imul ah
```

AX = (-1) * (-4) = (+4) = 0004h

```
imul al
```

AX = (+4) * (+4) = 16 = 0010h